# how to change background of a touchableOpacity in iteration

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am looping an array , wrapping each item into touchableOpacity  ,  attempting to change background Color of the clicked item on onPress event,
my issue is that its changing the background color of the whole items   , is there a way to change background Color to only the clicked item , here is my code

```
 return this.props.categes.map( (

            cat,i)=>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.changeBackground(i)} key = {i} style={{alignSelf : 'center', paddingLeft: 5, paddingRight : 7, paddingTop : 5, paddingBottom : 5, backgroundColor : this.state.background}}>
            <Text style={{color : '#838D8D'}}> {cat.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            )

  changeBackground(item){

        if(item)
        {
            this.setState({
                background: 'red'
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I have  made this example  and I hope this solves your problem.Find working example here.(https://snack.expo.io/@shrutigarg/touchableopacity-background-change-onclick)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categes: [
        { cat_id: '1', cat_name: 'abc', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
        { cat_id: '2', cat_name: 'xyz', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
        { cat_id: '3', cat_name: 'pqr', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
        { cat_id: '4', cat_name: 'uvw', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
        { cat_id: '5', cat_name: 'hij', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
      ],
      change: false,
    };
  }

  changeBackground = item => {
    let categes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.categes));

    for (let x = 0; x < this.state.categes.length; x++) {
      if (this.state.categes[x].cat_id == item.cat_id) {
        categes[x].backgroundcolor = '#0000FF';

        this.setState({
          categes: categes,
        });
      } else {
        categes[x].backgroundcolor = '#ED2525';

        this.setState({
          categes: categes,
        });
      }
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.categes.map((item, key) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 60,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              margin: 10,
              backgroundColor: item.backgroundcolor,
            }}
            onPress={() => this.changeBackground(item)}>
            <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>
              {' '}
              {item.cat_name.toUpperCase()}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code changes the color of all the items as it is unable to uniquely identify the item you clicked. The color you are changing is not associated with a particular item.

There are many ways to solve the problem. Here is one way where I create a separate component for each item, so each of these item's have their own state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View, Text } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let listOfItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {listOfItems.map(e => {
          return <ToggleButton key={e + "i"} />;
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ToggleButton extends Component {
  state = {
    on: false
  };

  render() {
    const { on } = this.state;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.setState({ on: !this.state.on })}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: on ? "green" : "red" }}
      >
        <Text>ITEM</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

[image: listcolor]

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference to `cat` and `index` directly, for that you should send the `Event.target`  it should work like this example:
I'm dispatching an event `onPress`, you should have access to the 
`event.target` inside of the onPress handler function.

```
return this.props.categes.map( (

            cat,i)=>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {event => this.changeBackground(i)} key = {i} style={{alignSelf : 'center', paddingLeft: 5, paddingRight : 7, paddingTop : 5, paddingBottom : 5, backgroundColor : this.state.background}}>
            <Text style={{color : '#838D8D'}}> {cat.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            )

  changeBackground(event){

     //Here you should be able to check the touched object:

     console.log('Here is the touched cat: ', event.target)

    }
```

Comment: thanks Natasha , so calling this.changeBackground I should also passing event ?

Comment: I think there is still something missing cause I am changing state of a component any propriety is inside that component calls that state it will get affected

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you provide context or refactor your question a little? Thanks